# PHPSpreadsheet - Conditional Formatting - Multiple conditions on cell

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to work out how to set multiple possible conditions in PHPSpreadsheet's conditional cell formatting and just can't seem to get it to work.

Given a table of the following as an example:

```
A1 | B1 | C1
A2 | B2 | C2
```

I want to format the cell (e.g. to be red) if the value is either: A1, B1 or C1.

I have tried adding multiple conditions, like so:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$cells = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'];

foreach ($cells as $cell) {

    $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $cell);

    $conditional1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
    $conditional1->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS);
    $conditional1->setOperatorType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL);
    $conditional1->addCondition('A1');
    $conditional1->addCondition('B1');
    $conditional1->addCondition('C1');
    $conditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
    $conditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $conditionalStyles = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles();
    $conditionalStyles[] = $conditional1;

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell)->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);

}
```

But it only ever picks up the first condition. So in the above example, only the cell A1 will be coloured red, as only the first rule is inserted into the excel file for those cells.

I have been trying to find documentation or examples on this for a couple of hours and can't seem to find any. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells

```
 $conditional1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
        $conditional1->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS);
        $conditional1->setOperatorType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::OPERATOR_LESSTHAN);
        $conditional1->addCondition('0');
        $conditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
        $conditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);
        
        $conditional2 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
        $conditional2->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS);
        $conditional2->setOperatorType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::OPERATOR_GREATERTHANOREQUAL);
        $conditional2->addCondition('0');
        $conditional2->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_GREEN);
        $conditional2->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);
        
        $conditionalStyles = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles();
        $conditionalStyles[] = $conditional1;
        $conditionalStyles[] = $conditional2;
        
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
    
    /* If you want to copy the ruleset to other cells, you can duplicate the style object:*/
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->duplicateStyle(
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2'),
            'B3:B7'
        );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.